# Running a PowerShell script on a remote Windows server using WinRM

Tags: powershell, winrm

I have written a script that allows to connect to a windows server machine using WinRM in order to run a script that exists on the Windows Server machine `PS_Block_Access_Internet_GPO.ps1` but the script is not executed despite that the session was well created.

Besides the script needs administrator privileges to be executed, so how can I provide the needed privileges for script using PowerShell.

```
Enable-PSRemoting
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName Server.Admin.6NLG-AD
.\PS_Block_Internet_Access_GPO.ps1
```

Answer (score 3):

To run a local script against a remote computer I would use use [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command), this doesn't need the script to be present on the remote computer.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 'Server.Admin.6NLG-AD' -FilePath C:\Folder\myScript.ps1
```

As your script looks to create a GPO, you may likely need to use an alternative user account with appropriate permissions on your domain...

You can use the `Credential` param to specify an account like this:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 'Server.Admin.6NLG-AD' -FilePath C:\Folder\myScript.ps1 -Credential Domain\Username
```

Comment: this works for a script that exists on the machine from which I'm going to open the session?

Comment: Yes, the script exists on the local computer and the commands within are run against the remote computer.