# Using New-ScheduledTaskAction to run a script with high privileges on a remote machine

Tags: powershell, winrm

I have written a script that allows to connect to a windows server machine using WinRM in order to run a script that exists on the Windows Server machine PS_Block_Access_Internet_GPO.ps1 with high privileges.But the script is not executed despite that the session was well created.

```
Enable-PSRemoting                                                                                                               
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName Server.Admin.6NLG-AD -ScriptBlock {                           
$TaskName = "RunPSScript"                                                                                                         
$User = "Admin\Server"                                                                                                   

$Scriptpath="C:Users\Administrateur\Desktop\PS_Block_Internet_Access_GPO.ps1"               
$Action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "PowerShell.exe" -Argument "- 
executionpolicy bypass -noprofile -file $Scriptpath"                                          
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $TaskName -User $User -Action $Action - 
RunLevel Highest -Force}
```

Comment: You didn't set a trigger to run the Task. Take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/register-scheduledtask?view=win10-ps

Comment: what if I don't need a time trigger,can I use Start-ScheduledTask instead?

Comment: Probaly... but why would you create a ScheduledTask without a trigger just to run it directly after creating?

Comment: the script PS_Block_Internet_Access requires higher priveleges so I used Scheduled Task to give it higher priveleges.but I want to run the script instantly,not at a specific time

Comment: Yeah I saw your other question, even though I think that (https://stackoverflow.com/a/54998490/6404133) is the better way to solve this issue. `Start-ScheduledTask` should work just fine to manually trigger the task.

Comment: In case I'm using Start-ScheduledTask , how precisely can I use it?

Comment: Its really not that hard... try to do some research yourself sometime... (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/start-scheduledtask?view=win10-ps)